# How do I auto-hide the Ubuntu Dock using gsettings on Ubuntu 17.10 and later?

Tags: gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock, dock, gsettings, autohide

In Ubuntu 17.04 with Unity I could auto-hide the launcher using this command:

```
dconf write "/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/launcher-hide-mode" 1
```

But this does not work in Ubuntu 17.10 with GNOME 3. Now the "launcher" has become the "dock" also.

Note: I can do it from the Settings menu: Settings->Dock and click the toggle button for "Auto-hide the Dock" to "On", this is fine, but I am interesting in a scripting solution using e.g., `gsettings`, such that this feature can be turned on automatically when I install a new Ubuntu machine.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Open Terminal and run

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock dock-fixed false
```

Then run

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock autohide true
```

Also you can toggle "intellihide" (dock dodges windows) on/off by

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock intellihide true/false
```

and set the intellihide mode by

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock intellihide-mode 'OPTION'
```

To get the available intellihide-mode options run

```
gsettings range org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock intellihide-mode
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it seems it does not work. If I first switch auto-hide off from the System settings, then run `gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock autohide true` the dock does not hide.

Comment: Ok, I turned off "intellihide": `gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock intellihide false`. Then I restarted my machine, and then checked that the settings for "autohide" was still there:  `gsettings get org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock autohide` --> `true`. But the launcher still does not auto-hide. (Using, the system settings menu still enables me to make it auto-hide, though)

Comment: I am also using Xorg session

Comment: I tried now `dconf write "/org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-dock/autohide" 1` but it does not work

Comment: @HåkonHægland I would not recommend editing system files, but as other methods are not working for you, as a last resort you may try overriding glib schemas. Run (as root) `echo autohide=true >> /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/10_ubuntu-dock.gschema.override` and then recompile it by `glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/`.

Comment: @HåkonHægland Sorry, I missed one command, now added as the first command. Could you please check now?