# Programatically hide Gnome desktop dock

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

How can I toggle the automatic dock hiding feature programmatically?

To be more precise, how can I toggle the feature from a command line script or toggle it with a shortcut?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically, you can achieve what you want by issuing the following commands on a terminal:

Enable smart autohide:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock dock-fixed false
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock autohide true
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock intellihide true
```

Disable smart autohide:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock dock-fixed true
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock autohide false
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock intellihide false
```

For more info check [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1005474/298047).